# I am not able to establish a serial communication between my arduino and python, i am using cvzone as i need it for the project

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, servo, cvzone

Here is my python code:

```
import cv2
import cvzone.SerialModule
from cvzone.SerialModule import SerialObject
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import serial

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = HandDetector(maxHands = 1, detectionCon = 0.7)
mySerial = SerialObject("COM7", 9600, 1)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    # The 'flipType' parameter flips the image, making it easier for some detections
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=True)
    if hands:
        # Gets fingers for the first detected hand
        fingers = detector.fingersUp(hands[0])
        print(fingers)
        mySerial.sendData(fingers)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

and this is the arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

#define numOfValsRec 5
#define digitsPerValRec 1

Servo servoThumb;
Servo servoIndex;
Servo servoMiddle;
Servo servoRing;
Servo servoPinky;

int valsRec[numOfValsRec];

int stringLength = numOfValsRec * digitsPerValRec +1;

int counter = 0;

bool counterStart = false;

String recievedString;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  servoThumb.attach(8);
  servoIndex.attach(9);
  servoMiddle.attach(10);
  servoRing.attach(11);
  servoPinky.attach(12);

}

void receiveData() {

  while(Serial.available())  {

    char c = Serial.read();

    if (c=='$'){
      counterStart = true;

    }

    if (counterStart){
      if (counter < stringLength) {

        recievedString = String(recievedString+c);
        counter++;

      }

      if (counter>= stringLength){

        for(int i = 0; i<numOfValsRec; i++) 
        {
          int num = (i*digitsPerValRec)+1;
        valsRec[i] = recievedString.substring(num,num + digitsPerValRec).toInt();
        }
        recievedString = "";
        counter = 0;
        counterStart = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

void loop(){ 


  receiveData();
  if (valsRec[0] == 1) {servoThumb.write(180);}else{servoThumb.write(0);}
  if (valsRec[1] == 1) {servoIndex.write(180);}else{servoIndex.write(0);}
  if (valsRec[2] == 1) {servoMiddle.write(180);}else{servoMiddle.write(0);}
  if (valsRec[3] == 1) {servoRing.write(180);}else{servoRing.write(0);}
  if (valsRec[4] == 1) {servoPinky.write(180);}else{servoPinky.write(0);} `


}
```

This is the error:

```
Attempt 1 of 5 to connect...
Attempt 1 failed. Retrying...
Attempt 2 of 5 to connect...
Attempt 2 failed. Retrying...
Attempt 3 of 5 to connect...
Attempt 3 failed. Retrying...
Attempt 4 of 5 to connect...
Attempt 4 failed. Retrying...
Attempt 5 of 5 to connect...
Attempt 5 failed. Retrying...
WARNING:root:Serial Device Not Connected. Max retries reached.
```

I basically 3d-printed a hand and when i move my hand in front of a camera, the hand moves accordingly. I need to sort this out for my exhibition, I have done everything like checking COM port, file name, installing just pyserial. Please help. If i just run my arduino and python code it works, the problem is in the communication.